Language or idiom of the sources of the answers
Is it necessary that the sources always be in the English language?
Under what conditions is it valid to answer questions from non-English sources?
It is a question that I have for a long time, I have always assumed that it is valid, for example if it is a very precise data of a very unusual investigation, but on the other hand somehow I have always forced myself to find the materials in English language. We should specify certain situations because I think I have not been able to be as specific as I would like in some answers.
So:
Should the questioners be asked if they want a data from a source in another language?
Should I always deal with a translation in addition to the response?
In the latter case should I translate the entire document?

I would definitely encourage use of accessible literature, i.e., English, which is the norm in science. However, German literature is quite prominent too, for example in Chemistry and I think as well in Psychology. Spanish, Chinese and Indian sources are pretty inaccessible to those who don't know it, so I would discourage those, even when acknowledging when they make up about half of all folks on this planet.

I agree with AliceD. But, if you can only find a Spanish /Chinese source, I would accept such a source of you could translate the abstract so that it is clear what the paper was about specifically.
